# How to set PHP error messages to Session Variable?

Tags: php

How can store the php code error messages to session variable so that i can access to the error messages to another page:

Eg:

```
$_SESSION[error] = error_reporting(0);
```

Output:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data' in F:\Currnet
>   Source\Infogreen\root\Advocate\lib\script\error_session.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: data in F:\Currnet
>   Source\Infogreen\root\Advocate\lib\script\error_session.php on line 5

Please Help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: Using exceptions. Just get php error and that's it. Also you can write custom messages and save in session. P.S. Don't forget to start session.

Answer (score 1):

You must enclose the error variable name, putting it without any enclosing quotes means that it is a CONSTANT

```
$_SESSION['error'] = 'Your error code here';
```